# How do I add texts on each specific page?

Tags: dart, flutter

I've written some code that opens up a new container every time when you press the add button. Each of these containers opens up RPage(check the code if you don't understand).

**Code:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:io';

void main() => runApp(MainPage());

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp ( 
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home:Scaffold (
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        body: Column (
          children: <Widget> [
            Container (
              height: 100.0
            ),
            Body(),
          ]
        )
      )
    );
  }

}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();

}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {

  final String open1 = 'open';

  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded (
      child: Container (
        child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification> (
          onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
            overscroll.disallowGlow();
          },
          child: PageView.builder(
            reverse: true,
            pageSnapping: false,
            controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85),
            itemCount: count,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              if (i == 0) {
                return GestureDetector (
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute (
                        builder: (context) => RPage (
                          open: open1,
                        )
                      ),
                    );
                    count++;
                  },
                  child: Hero (
                    tag: open1,
                    child: Padding (
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15
                      ),
                      child: Material (
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                        color: Colors.white,
                        elevation: 8.0,
                        child: InkWell (
                          child: Column (
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                            children: <Widget> [
                              Icon (
                                Icons.add,
                                size: 30.0,
                                color: Colors.black,
                              )
                            ]
                          ),
                        )                        
                      )
                    )
                  )
                );
              } 
              else {
                return RCard(i);
              }
            }
          )
        )
      )
    );
  }

}

class RCard extends StatefulWidget {

  final int count;

  RCard(this.count);

  @override
  RCardState createState() => RCardState();

}

class RCardState extends State<RCard> {

  int count;

  String open2;

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();

    count = widget.count;

    open2 = 'open$count';

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero (
      tag: open2,
      child: GestureDetector (
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute (
              builder: (context) => RPage (
                open: open2,
              )
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Padding (
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
            right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
            top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15
          ),
          child: Material (
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
            color: Colors.white,
            elevation: 8.0,
          )
        )
      ),
    );
  }

}

class RPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String open;

  RPage({this.open});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector (
      child: Hero (
        tag: open,
        child: Material (
          child: Container (
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Center (
              child: RBody()
            )
          )
        )
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}

class Constants {

 static const String add = 'Add';

 static const List<String> choices = <String>[

   add

 ];

}

class RBody extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  RBodyState createState() => RBodyState();

}

class RBodyState extends State<RBody> {

  final String open1 = 'open';

  static bool platform;

  static int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      platform = true;
    }

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      platform = false;
    }

    return Column (
      children: <Widget> [
        Container (
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
          child: Row (
            children: <Widget> [
              Expanded (
                child: Container (
                  alignment: Alignment(-0.9, 1.0),
                  child: IconButton (
                    iconSize: 15.0,
                    icon: Icon (Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                  )
                ),
              ),
              Expanded (
                child: Container (
                  alignment: Alignment(0.9, 1.0),
                  child: platform ? RotatedBox (
                    quarterTurns: 1,
                    child: PopupMenuButton<String> (
                      onSelected: (_) {   
                        setState(() {
                          count ++;
                        });
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Constants.choices.map(
                          (String choice) {
                            return PopupMenuItem<String> (
                              value: choice,
                              child: Text(choice)
                            );
                          }
                        ).toList();
                      },
                    )
                  ) :
                  PopupMenuButton<String> (
                    onSelected: (_) {
                      setState(() {
                        count ++;
                      });
                    },
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                      return Constants.choices.map(
                        (String choice) {
                          return PopupMenuItem<String> (
                            value: choice,
                            child: Text(choice)
                          );
                        }
                      ).toList();
                    },
                  )
                )
              )
            ]
          ),
        ),
        Title(),
        Padding (
             padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
               vertical: platform ? 10.0 : 30.0
             ),
           ),
        Expanded (
          child: Align (
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container (
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.34,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.0,
              child: RList()
            )
          )
        )
      ]
    );
  }

}

class RList extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  RListState createState() => RListState();

}

class RListState extends State<RList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification> (
      onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
        overscroll.disallowGlow();
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
        controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85),
        itemCount: RBodyState.count,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          if (i == 0) {

            return Container();

          } else {

            return Cell(i);

          }
        }
      )
    );
  }

}

class Title extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container (
      color: Colors.white,
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
      child: Align (
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: Material (
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text (
            'T I T L E',
            style: TextStyle (
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20.0,
            ),
          )
        )
      )    
    );
  }

}

class Cell extends StatefulWidget {

  final int count;

  Cell(this.count);

  @override
  CellState createState() => CellState();

}

class CellState extends State<Cell> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column (
      children: <Widget> [
        Material (
          color: Colors.white,
          child: Text (
            'T E X T',
            style: TextStyle (
              fontSize: 12.0,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            ),
          )
        ),
        Padding (
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025
          ),
        ),
      ]  
    );  
  }

}
```

RPage will create new texts every time you press the popup menu button. But I was expecting that there would be texts added only on that specific page.
But, I found out that my code adds texts on every single page. How can I make the text add on only one specific page?

Comment: It'll take a lot of changes in you code as you have multiple classes and it'll take passing down data in the hierarchy many steps down in your code so that you can achieve what you want to do. But seeing your code i'ld suggest you one thing this is at all an approach that will not help you at all. You have already made your code a lot complicated than it actually might have been. try using redux for this problem. it'll be the best use case for that. what you are trying to achieve is simple but you have made it complicated

Comment: @AmanMalhotra can you give me an example with redux and flutter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are not aware about redux at all in flutter. It'll seem a little too complicated in the starting but if you get to learn redux before looking at this then u'll see that this is way too easy to manage state in redux without making your code complicated at all. but u'll have to make more files to keep your code ordered. I have uploaded  the code on github the link to which is given here you can clone that project and try for yourself [Redux Card Example](https://github.com/aman-malhotra-1999/ReduxExampleCards)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:
in your RBodyState class

```
static int count = 1;
```

As your count variable is static, all instances have same value of count and as a result all of your pages have same number of 'T I T L E's.

Use following code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'dart:io';

void main() => runApp(MainPage());

class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp (
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home:Scaffold (
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            body: Column (
                children: <Widget> [
                  Container (
                      height: 100.0
                  ),
                  Body(),
                ]
            )
        )
    );
  }

}

class Body extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  _BodyState createState() => _BodyState();

}

class _BodyState extends State<Body> {

  final String open1 = 'open';

  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded (
        child: Container (
            child: NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification> (
                onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
                  overscroll.disallowGlow();
                },
                child: PageView.builder(
                    reverse: true,
                    pageSnapping: false,
                    controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85),
                    itemCount: count,
                    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                      if (i == 0) {
                        return GestureDetector (
                            onTap: () {
                              Navigator.push(
                                context,
                                MaterialPageRoute (
                                    builder: (context) => RPage (
                                      open: open1,
                                    )
                                ),
                              );
                              count++;
                            },
                            child: Hero (
                                tag: open1,
                                child: Padding (
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                        left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                                        right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                                        top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                                        bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15
                                    ),
                                    child: Material (
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        elevation: 8.0,
                                        child: InkWell (
                                          child: Column (
                                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                              children: <Widget> [
                                                Icon (
                                                  Icons.add,
                                                  size: 30.0,
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                )
                                              ]
                                          ),
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        );
                      }
                      else {
                        return RCard(i);
                      }
                    }
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }

}

class RCard extends StatefulWidget {

  final int count;

  RCard(this.count);

  @override
  RCardState createState() => RCardState();

}

class RCardState extends State<RCard> {

  int count;

  String open2;

  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();

    count = widget.count;

    open2 = 'open$count';

  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Hero (
      tag: open2,
      child: GestureDetector (
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute (
                  builder: (context) => RPage (
                    open: open2,
                  )
              ),
            );
          },
          child: Padding (
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  left: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                  right: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.015,
                  top: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08,
                  bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.15
              ),
              child: Material (
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 8.0,
              )
          )
      ),
    );
  }

}

class RPage extends StatelessWidget {

  final String open;

  RPage({this.open});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector (
      child: Hero (
          tag: open,
          child: Material (
              child: Container (
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Center (
                      child: RBody()
                  )
              )
          )
      ),
      onTap: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      },
    );
  }
}

class Constants {

  static const String add = 'Add';

  static const List<String> choices = <String>[

    add

  ];

}

class RBody extends StatefulWidget {

  @override
  RBodyState createState() => RBodyState();

}

class RBodyState extends State<RBody> {

  final String open1 = 'open';

  static bool platform;

  int count = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if (Platform.isIOS) {
      platform = true;
    }

    if (Platform.isAndroid) {
      platform = false;
    }

    return Column (
        children: <Widget> [
          Container (
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.15,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
            child: Row (
                children: <Widget> [
                  Expanded (
                    child: Container (
                        alignment: Alignment(-0.9, 1.0),
                        child: IconButton (
                          iconSize: 15.0,
                          icon: Icon (Icons.arrow_back_ios),
                          onPressed: () {
                            Navigator.pop(context);
                          },
                        )
                    ),
                  ),
                  Expanded (
                      child: Container (
                          alignment: Alignment(0.9, 1.0),
                          child: platform ? RotatedBox (
                              quarterTurns: 1,
                              child: PopupMenuButton<String> (
                                onSelected: (_) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    count ++;
                                  });
                                },
                                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                                  return Constants.choices.map(
                                          (String choice) {
                                        return PopupMenuItem<String> (
                                            value: choice,
                                            child: Text(choice)
                                        );
                                      }
                                  ).toList();
                                },
                              )
                          ) :
                          PopupMenuButton<String> (
                            onSelected: (_) {
                              setState(() {
                                count ++;
                              });
                            },
                            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return Constants.choices.map(
                                      (String choice) {
                                    return PopupMenuItem<String> (
                                        value: choice,
                                        child: Text(choice)
                                    );
                                  }
                              ).toList();
                            },
                          )
                      )
                  )
                ]
            ),
          ),
          Title(),
          Padding (
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: platform ? 10.0 : 30.0
            ),
          ),
          Expanded (
              child: Align (
                  alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                  child: Container (
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.34,
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1.0,
                      child: RList(count)
                  )
              )
          )
        ]
    );
  }

}

class RList extends StatefulWidget {

  int count;


  RList(this.count);

  @override
  RListState createState() => RListState();

}

class RListState extends State<RList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return NotificationListener<OverscrollIndicatorNotification> (
        onNotification: (OverscrollIndicatorNotification overscroll) {
          overscroll.disallowGlow();
        },
        child: ListView.builder(
            controller: PageController(viewportFraction: 0.85),
            itemCount: widget.count,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) {
              if (i == 0) {

                return Container();

              } else {

                return Cell(i);

              }
            }
        )
    );
  }

}

class Title extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container (
        color: Colors.white,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.2,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 1.0,
        child: Align (
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Material (
                color: Colors.white,
                child: Text (
                  'T I T L E',
                  style: TextStyle (
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize: 20.0,
                  ),
                )
            )
        )
    );
  }

}

class Cell extends StatefulWidget {

  final int count;

  Cell(this.count);

  @override
  CellState createState() => CellState();

}

class CellState extends State<Cell> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column (
        children: <Widget> [
          Material (
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Text (
                'T E X T',
                style: TextStyle (
                  fontSize: 12.0,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              )
          ),
          Padding (
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                vertical: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.025
            ),
          ),
        ]
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I think I have a problem. When I press the container and add texts and then go out then press the container again, the texts will be all gone. How can I fix this?

Comment: Store count in some structure like Map, with container id as key and number of count as value. And every time you come back to your previous container, fetch number of counts from that map.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: After I gave you this idea, have you tried anything,..?? if yes, then post your code I will correct you if you are facing any problems..